# Possible typo: What does Bachman (Functional Analysis) mean with $\overline{A} = \overline{A}$?

Tags: general-topology

From Bachman's functional analysis, here is theorem 7.1

> Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$. Then
>
> (1) $A\subset B \implies \overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$
>
> (2) $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$
>
> (3) $\overline{A} = \overline{A}$

The third one seems a bit funny, but that's exactly what he then goes on to prove. Is there another well known property of subsets of topological spaces that he probably meant to include instead of this one?

Comment: Have you looked at the proof? What is it proving?

Comment: He first proves that $\overline{A}\subset \overline{A}$, and then that if something is in $\overline{A}$ it's also in $\overline{A}$. So the typo carries on in the proof...

Comment: ok... well if the proof really goes like that, it is unlikely that this a typo... or this a big typo and "he first proves that $\overline A \subset \overline{\overline{A}}$, and then that if something is in $\overline{\overline{A}}$ it's also in $\overline{A}$"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably was $\overline{\overline A}=\overline A$. From (1) you have $\overline A\subseteq \overline{\overline A}$ for $B=\overline A$. But $\overline A$ is closed.